# Angular plugin ZeroClipboard not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zeroclipboard

I'm rather new to Angular. I'm trying to use a module called [ZeroClipboard](https://github.com/lisposter/angular-zeroclipboard).

I eddited my application to load the module and set the config as described in the demo.

```
var app = angular.module('JpqlEditor', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap', 'toaster', 'chieffancypants.loadingBar', 'zeroclipboard']).
  config(['uiZeroclipConfigProvider', function(uiZeroclipConfigProvider) {

    // config ZeroClipboard
    uiZeroclipConfigProvider.setZcConf({
      swfPath: 'assets/flash/ZeroClipboard.swf'
    });

  }])
```

In my HTML I added the same structure as in the demo:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myText" />
<button ui-zeroclip zeroclip-copied="copied=true" zeroclip-model="myText">Copy</button>
<span ng-show="copied">Text Copied!</span>
```

However, on page load I'm getting following error:

[image]

I don't see where I went wrong, I followed all the steps explained. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you must have missed to add zeroClip 2.0 library

Comment: @pankajparkar I included angular-zeroclipboard.js and ZeroClipboard.js

Comment: does there sequence in proper? 1st `ZeroClipboard.js` then `angular-zeroclipboard.js`

Comment: @pankajparkar that appeared to be the problem! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have missed to add `ZeroClipboard.js` & script sequence of loading should be

1. `ZeroClipboard.js`
2. `angular-zeroclipboard.js`

Thanks :)